# javascript not executing on my html page - attempting to maintain bootstrap accordion state

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 accordion, card and collpase classes to create an accordion on my html page. This works nicely.

The difficulty I am having is maintaining the state of the accordion when leaving and then returning to my page. As can be seen in the supplied code, the first card in the accordion is expanded by default. The second card has a link to the Google home page. When I expand this card and click the Google link, I want it to take me to the Google home page, which it does. But when I click the back button, I want it to return me to my page with card 2 of the accordion expanded. What actually happens is that it displays the accordion with card 1 expanded i.e. as if it was loading the page for the first time.

I have added some JavaScript at the bottom of the html and this calls out to a set of methods in a js file (referenced at the top and the bottom of my html). I was hoping that this would address the problem detailed above. For ease of testing, the html file and the js file are in the same directory.

```js
function restoreAccordionPanel(storageKey, accordionId) {
  alert("This is alert box!");
  var activeItem = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  if (activeItem) {
    //remove default collapse settings
    $(accordionId + " .panel-collapse").removeClass('in');

    //show the account_last visible group
    $("#" + activeItem).addClass("in");
  }
}

function restoreActiveTab(storageKey, tabId) {
  var activeItem = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  if (activeItem) {
    $(tabId + ' a[href="' + activeItem + '"]').tab('show');
  }
}

function saveActiveAccordionPanel(storageKey, e) {
  alert("This is alert box!");
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, e.target.id);
}

function saveActiveTab(storageKey, e) {
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, $(e.target).attr('href'));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
  <script src="./bootstrapHelpers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="alert()">Show alert dialog</button>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          Sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin <a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a> nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
          labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bootstrapHelpers.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
          alert("This is alert box!");
          saveActiveAccordionPanel('accordion-activePanel', e);
        })
      )
    };
    restoreAccordionPanel('accordion-activePanel', '#accordion');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, it appears that my JavaScript functions are not being called. To test this further, I have added some alert statements, but these are not being displayed. I can see that JavaScript is enabled ok because I am successfully calling an alert from the onclick method of the simple button at the top of the html page.

I am inexperienced in JavaScript and I think there must either be something wrong with the JS code and/or the way I am referencing or calling it. I would very much appreciate any ideas or guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the specific `accordion` is opened it add class `show` to the div and the clicked tab gets opened. To save the opened tab, add click listener to `a` which are enclosed in `accordian` and then get the element which have class `show`, get the `id` of that element and store in `localStorage`. On page load, retrieve the stored `id` and get an element which have this `id`. Before adding `show` class to this element, remove the `show` class from all `div`s and add `show` to the filtered `div`.

Following code is the additional code required -

```
$('a').on('click',function() {
    const activeEleId = $('.accordion div').filter('.show').attr('id');
    saveActiveTab('active', activeEleId);
});

$( document ).ready( function() {
    const lastActiveTabID = localStorage.getItem('active');
    $('.accordion div[id]').removeClass('show');
    $('.accordion').find('#' + lastActiveTabID).addClass('show');
});
```

Due to `sandboxing`, code does not work in snippet. Below is full code.

```js
function restoreAccordionPanel(storageKey, accordionId) {
  // alert("This is alert box!");
  var activeItem = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  if (activeItem) {
    //remove default collapse settings
    $(accordionId + " .panel-collapse").removeClass('in');

    //show the account_last visible group
    $("#" + activeItem).addClass("in");
  }
}

function restoreActiveTab(storageKey, tabId) {
  var activeItem = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  if (activeItem) {
    $(tabId + ' a[href="' + activeItem + '"]').tab('show');
  }
}

function saveActiveAccordionPanel(storageKey, e) {
  // alert("This is alert box!"); 
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, e.target.id);
}

function saveActiveTab(storageKey, e) {
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, e);
}

$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  alert("This is alert box!");
  saveActiveAccordionPanel('accordion-activePanel', e);
});

restoreAccordionPanel('accordion-activePanel', '#accordion');

// Added Code
$('a').on('click', function() {
  const activeEleId = $('.accordion div').filter('.show').attr('id');
  saveActiveTab('active', activeEleId);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  const lastActiveTabID = localStorage.getItem('active');
  $('.accordion div[id]').removeClass('show');
  $('.accordion').find('#' + lastActiveTabID).addClass('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="alert()">Show alert dialog</button>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
                </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
                </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <!-- show -->
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin <a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a> nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant - this worked first time for me. Accepted answer. I hugely appreciate you explaining and supplying the new code - makes it very easy for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute your code when the document ready event fires.

`$(document).ready(function(){  //execute your code here  });`

Comment: I already accepted the previous answer, but this is also useful and has been saved to my notes! Thank you